# this/that with time expressions

Tags: word-choice, determiners

"This" can refer to situations and events which are going on or just about to start. "That" can refer to situations and events which have just finished, or which are more distant in the past.

Those rules usually works but what about "this morning" or "that morning"? The first is kind of a set phrase but can I use the second?

Answer (score 1):

"This morning" is always the morning of the current day. "That morning" is a specified morning in the past or future.